# What is the proper way to handle a back button event in Android?

Tags: java, android, mobile

This is what I have.

[image]

This is the problem.

[image]

What should I do to avoid this warning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, @NonNull KeyEvent event)
```

and add:

```
import android.support.annotation.NoNNull;
```

Look also: [Meaning of Android Studio error: Not annotated parameter overrides @NotNull parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728627/meaning-of-android-studio-error-not-annotated-parameter-overrides-notnull-para)

Next time post the code directly as text.

Comment: If the answer is the same as another question please mark it as duplicate.

Comment: I did that and it said, "Cannot resolve symbol support" at the import statement.