# onCreateDialog not annotated method overrides method annotated with @NonNull

Tags: android

I am creating DialogFragment and when I want to override `onCreateDialog` I receive the following warning:

> not annotated method overrides method annotated with @NonNull

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}
```

If I want to place that annotation to my method, Android Studio can't find that annotation.

Why is this happening? Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Meaning of Android Studio error: Not annotated parameter overrides @NotNull parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728627/meaning-of-android-studio-error-not-annotated-parameter-overrides-notnull-para)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you override a method which is defined with a @NonNull annotation (meaning the method must not return null), and you are not using the same annotation in your overridden implementation, so that makes it a mismatch.

Please search for your question before submitting, this is asked many times.

[Meaning of Android Studio error: Not annotated parameter overrides @NonNull parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728627/meaning-of-android-studio-error-not-annotated-parameter-overrides-notnull-para)

(Edit: Fixed meaning of @NonNull annotation, thanks ci_)

Comment: Thank you. I've tried to import `android.support.annotation.NoNNull` but Android Studio can't find annotation. That solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @JHH you didn't read the question right, the principle is the same, but the details are different. In this case the method is annotated with @NonNull, which means you cannot return `null` from it. The `savedInstanceState` parameter can very well be null. This case is even specifically mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Thanks @ci_. Apparently I was too quick.

Answer (score 17):

Looking at definition of the `onCreateDialog` method in `DialogFragment`, you will see:

```
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

So your code should include the same `@NonNull` annotation like this:

```
@Override
@NonNull
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
}
```