# Unclear inspection warning "NullableProblems" in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-inspection

Why am I getting a warning from the "NullableProblems" inspection in IntelliJ on this:

```
public class Test implements Comparable<Test> {
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Test o) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm using IntelliJ 14.1.4 and compiling with Java 1.7

Screenshot:

[image]

Adding `@NotNull` before the argument doesn't help:

[image]

Comment: Read everything about ``@Nullable`` and ``@NotNull`` features [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728627/meaning-of-android-studio-error-not-annotated-parameter-overrides-nonnull-para

Comment: @davidgiga1993 Not a duplicate. I'm overriding a method that doesn't have the `@NotNull` annotation.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

From `Comparable.compareTo`:

```
@throws NullPointerException if the specified object is null
```

So IntelliJ knows, that the object should not be `null` and adds a `@NotNull` annotation [automatically](http://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/10/automatic-notnullnullablecontract-inference-in-intellij-idea-14/):

> IntelliJ IDEA will look carefully at SDK and libraries bytecode and will infer these annotations automatically so that they can later be used to analyze source code to spot places where you overlooked null.

Your overriden method doesn't include this annotation, so it *overrides* this behavior making the parameter nullable - against the contract of the `Comparable` interface.

You can solve this by adding `@NotNull` before the parameter.

You can also disable this inspection by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>, selecting the warning in the popup menu and selecting `Disable inspection` in the sub-menu.

Check out the [Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html) and [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use) for more information about `@NotNull` / `@NonNull` annotations.

Comment: Hmm, now I understand where the original warning comes from (checking the super class was the first thing I checked), but when I added `@NotNull` it didn't clear the warning... (updated original question with screenshot).

Comment: You are using the "wrong" `@NotNull` annotation. There are [several NotNull/NonNull annotations](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300/which-notnull-java-annotation-should-i-use) out there, non of them included in the JDK. You will need to include and use one of those. Also check out the [Web Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/documentation/howto.html).

Comment: Ha! Strange, when I added the @NotNull the import is what IntelliJ added automatically (after alt-enter I mean). I looked at the other question you linked to and I assume that `com.intellij.annotations.NotNull` is the correct annotation, but it seems that IntelliJ can't find the class...

Comment: I will post a new question about that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31243474/intellij-suggests-wrong-notnull-annotation

Comment: You need to include the jar file containing the annotations. You can download (or include via Maven) IntelliJ annotations [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intellij/annotations/12.0). Another common alternative is `javax.annotation.Nonnull` (not NotNull), which you can find [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.annotation/jsr250-api/1.0). Both are recognized by IntelliJ.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out this solves it (see the other question I posted), but I don't understand why IntelliJ originally suggests the wrong import and only when I add the jar it gets it right. Is that normal?

Comment: You have the control over your classpath. Unless a Jar is added to your classpath, an IDE won't provide any autocompletion. One reason is performance - imagine IntelliJ showing all possible classes, even if they are not included in your project.

Comment: Aha, I guess that makes sense. I was worried there's something wrong with my IntelliJ installation. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14):

This can be globally configured in IntelliJ IDEA easily and for me personally is the recommended way. If you want you can add your own annotations.
i.e. `javax.validation.constraints.NotNull`

Path to the setting:
`Settings > Editor > Inspections > @NotNull/@Nullable problems > Configure annotations`

Some screenshots:
[image]
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Its because that you are overriding a method that does not have a `@NotNull` annotation.

IntelliJ IDEA warns you if the overriding method does not have a `@NotNull` annotation.

Comment: Nope. Check the interface.